# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I'm getting (see below)

```
ProjectsControllerTest#test_should_redirect_create_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches{:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"} missing required keys: [:id]
test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
```

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails, however I've been looking around and trying different things with no joy. I know that the project :id is not being sent but I cannot figure out why

Routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
 get 'password_resets/new'
 get 'password_resets/edit'
 get 'sessions/new'
 get 'users/new'

 root 'static_pages#home'
 get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
 get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
 get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
 get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
 get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
 post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
 delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users do

member do
  get :following, :followers
end
 end
  resources :users
  resources :account_activation, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,    only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,         only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,      only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :projects
end
```

Project.model.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  before_save {name.downcase!}
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name && :category, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create]
before_action :project_owner,   only: :destroy

def index
end

def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save
        flash[:success] = "Project Created"
        redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    @project.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Project Deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name,:category,:picture)
end

def project_owner
      @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if project.nil?
end
end
```

and finally this is the test suit I'm running

projects_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

   def setup
    @project = projects(:Charity)
  end

  test "should redirect create when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'Project.count' do
      post project_path, params: { project: {name:  "  ",
                                         category: "  " } }
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

---   Edit 1   ----

```
       projects GET    /projects(.:format)                    projects#index
                POST   /projects(.:format)                    projects#create
    new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                projects#new
   edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)           projects#edit
        project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#show
                PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#update
                PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#update
                DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#destroy
```

Comment: Check your routes by running `rake routes`. Judging from your test error, It looks to me that you are not calling the correct path. Your test specifies the create path but you are calling your show path.

Comment: project_path is returns the path to a specific project, thus the id of that project is required (e.g project_path, {id: @project.id, project: {name.....}})
The problem is that you really want to use projects_path instead. (Which is used for creating new projects and doesn't require any id)

Comment: Do you have that view template? (In app/views/projects/new.html.erb)

Comment: Where is the :id established within your test?  I don't see it

Comment: Ok one problem at a time. @sammygadd is correct in his comment, regarding your paths. In your original problem with the test "should redirect create when not logged in" you are not calling the correct path. Your rake routes confirms this. Calling `post projects_path` will fix it. The next error you have is completely separate. It looks like you don't have a projects/new html erb file.

Comment: Yes! I do have a new template in that folder (In app/views/projects/new.html.erb). Thank you all by the way!

Comment: Silly me! Forgot I had to be logged in in order to pass that test ... Ups! Now is good thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from here:

```
  post project_path, params: { project: {name:  "  ",
                                     category: "  " } }
```

You need to pass an id attribute in the project hash

This is because you are using the standard show route generated by resources which required an id.